# How to use spinner with multiple enqueueActions

Tags: apex, lightning

I have init function with multiple enqueueActions (to select data for different object). I want to start spinner, run all actions, stop spinner. Because all actions fire asynchronously what is the best way to toggle the spinner? 
Example of one aciton:

```
var action = component.get('c.getSobjectsToAdd');
action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
        var availableToAddObjects = a.getReturnValue();
        component.set('v.availableToAddObjects',availableToAddObjects);
    } else 
    if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {
        helper.showToast(component, event, helper, 'Error', a.getError(), 'error');
    }            
});

$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to count the number of actions and remove the spinner when you're done. Here's my implementation, basically an in-flight counter:

```
<aura:attribute name="actionCounter" type="Integer" default="0" />
<aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<lightning:spinner class="{!v.showSpinner?'':'slds-hide'}" />
```

---

```
// helper methods
callServer: function(component, method, params, success, failure) {
  var action = component.get(method), 
      counter = component.get("v.actionCounter") + 1;
  if(counter === 1) {
    component.set("v.actionCounter", counter);
  }
  action.setParams(params);
  action.setCallback(
    function(result) {
      var counter = component.get("v.actionCounter") - 1,
          state = component.getState();
      if(counter === 0) {
        component.set("v.showSpinner", false);
      }
      component.set("v.actionCounter", counter);
      if(state === "SUCCESS" || state === "DRAFT") {
        success(component, result.getReturnValue());
      } else {
        failure(component, result.getError());
      }
    }
  );
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

---

You would call the method from other helper methods like this:

```
this.callServer(component, "c.doSomething", params, this.doSomethingResponse, this.doSomethingError);
```

---

## Example 2

## CONTROLLER

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.doInit(component);
    }
})
```

## HELPER

```
({
    // helper methods
    callServer: function (component, method, params, success, failure) {
        var action = component.get(method),
            counter = component.get("v.actionCounter") + 1;
        if (counter === 1) {
            component.set("v.actionCounter", counter);
        }
        action.setParams(params);
        action.setCallback(
            function (result) {
                var counter = component.get("v.actionCounter") - 1,
                    state = component.getState();
                if (counter === 0) {
                    component.set("v.showSpinner", false);
                }
                component.set("v.actionCounter", counter);
                if (state === "SUCCESS" || state === "DRAFT") {
                    success(component, result.getReturnValue());
                } else {
                    failure(component, result.getError());
                }
            }
        );
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    doInit: function (component) {
        this.callServer(component, "c.getSobjectsToAdd", {}, this.getSobjectsToAddResult, this.showError);
        // Change this as appropriate //
        this.callServer(component, "c.otherMethod", {}, this.otherMethodResult, this.showError);
    },
    getSobjectsToAddResult: function (component, result) {
        component.set("v.availableToAddObjects", result);
    },
    otherMethodResult: function (component, result) {
        // ... not included here ... //
    },
    showError: function (component, error) {
        this.showToast(component, 'Error', error, 'error');
    },
    showToast: function (component, title, errorMessage, variant) {
        // ... not included here ... //
    }
})
```

Comment: seems like my implementation is different or maybe wrong. I have init function and two enqueueAction one by one. Should I call callServer function in the beginning of each of my function? Below is an example of one my action:

Comment: added example of action to the original post

Comment: @EugeneVabishchevich I've added a second expanded code section that demonstrates what your code would look like. Does this help?